# ValueError: unsupported format character '<' (0x3c) at index 3

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

```
HTML_BODY=  """ <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    table {color: #333;font-family: calibri; width: 80%%;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
        td, th { border: 1px solid #CCC;width:100px; height: 30px; }
        th {background: #F3F3F3;font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;}
        td {background: #FAFAFA;text-align: center; font-size: 12px;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    S.No.</th>
                <th>
                    Scenario Name</th>
                <th>
                    Total Test Cases</th>
                <th>
                    Passed Test Cases</th>
                <th>
                    Failed Test Cases</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    1</td>
                <td>
                    %s%</td>
                <td>
                    %s%</td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#008000;">%s%</span></td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:#ff0000;">%s%</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Total Scenario</th>
                <th>
                    Total Test Cases</th>
                <th>
                    Passed Test Cases</th>
                <th>
                    Failed Test Cases</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    %s%</td>
                <td>
                    %s%</td>
                <td style="color:#008000;">
                    %s%</td>
                <td style="color:#ff0000;">
                    %s%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

""" %(self.__flow,self.__totalflowtestcases,self.__flowtestpass,self.__flowtestfail,self.__alltestcases,self.__alltestcases,self.__testpass,self.__testfail)

and then i am getting error : ValueError: unsupported format character '<' (0x3c) at index 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Now, please take the tour and read what is required to actually ask a question (e.g. showing that you actually put some effort into it yourself, showing what you tried etc.).

Comment: i tried lot of stuff to resolve the error. I am adding my code in question

Comment: Here i also user .format(value) method and then change %s with {0} . But then i am getting Key Error 'color'

Comment: What code caused that error?

Comment: its showing below error :  """ %(self.__flow,self.__totalflowtestcases,self.__flowtestpass,self.__flowtestfail,self.__alltestcases,self.__alltestcases,self.__testpass,self.__testfail)
ValueError: unsupported format character '<' (0x3c) at index 3

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this line(s):

```
%s%</td>
```

`%<` is assumed a format string by Python interpreter. If you want to print `%` sign inside a format string, use `%%`, ie:

```
%s%%</td>
```

Comment: Hi Selcuk.. i got the solution.. thanks for your suggestion.From Premailer module i converted my css to inline html.. and its working fine..Thanks